# unauthorized (response: {"note":"not authorized for command: enablesharding on database admin","ok":0.0,"errmsg":"unauthorized"})

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have deployed sharded cluster of mongodb on server. And also enabled authentication by providing keyFile. Before enabling authentication I have added user by assigning password and roles. After that I have restarted all the clusters by applying key file.

But when my application tries to do enablesharding (using mongodb c# driver) using the admin database then I get error message as : **`"Command 'enablesharding' failed: unauthorized (response: {"note":"not authorized for command: enablesharding on database admin","ok":0.0,"errmsg":"unauthorized"}) "`**

Roles I have given to user are as : **"roles" : [ "readWriteAnyDatabase", "userAdminAnyDatabase", "readAnyDatabase", "dbAdminAnyDatabase", "dbOwner", "clusterAdmin", "clusterManager", "clusterMonitor", "hostManager", "backup", "restore" ]**

Can you please suggest me some solution over this.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a question about administration of MongoDB, not about programming for it. This means that this question belongs on https://dba.stackexchange.com. While the question is being migrated, you should add information about what roles with what permissions you assigned to the user you are doing this with.

Comment: I'm not sure why this hasn't moved to dba.stackexchange.com yet, but could you provide the C# code you're using to run this command and, specifically, the code you're using to authenticate?